# Calculate result of formula

Tags: assembly, x86

Can someone help me solve this problem in Assembly language in signed and unsigned representation?

My task is to calculate the result of the following term:

```
(a*a+b)/(b+b)+c
```

where `a` is a word, `b` is a byte , and `c` a doubleword

I tried this:

```
assume CS:code, DS:data
data segment
    a dw 1
    b db 2
    c dd 3
    x dd ?
data ends
code segment
    start:
        mov ax, data
        mov ds, ax

        mov ax, a   ; AX = a
        mul a       ; AX = a*a
        add ax, 2   ; AX = a*a + 2

        mov bl, b   ; BX = b
        add bl, b   ; BX = b*b  
        div bl      ; a*a+b/b+b
        mov ax, word ptr c+2
        mov dx, word ptr c
        add ax, word ptr c
        mov word ptr x+2, dx
        mov word ptr x, ax

        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
    code ends
end start
```

Comment: Please read [ask] before continuing to use Stackoverflow as it will save you a great deal of unnecessary grief.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes, but i receive wrong result...

Answer (score 1):

```
mov ax, a   ; AX = a
mul a       ; AX = a*a
```

Wrong comment: The result of this `mul` is in DX:AX

```
add ax, 2   ; AX = a*a + 2
```

I don't think you're supposed to add *b* as an immediate!

```
mov bl, b   ; BX = b
add bl, b   ; BX = b*b
```

Wrong comment: It's an addition.

```
div bl      ; a*a+b/b+b
```

You would better make this a word division by zeroing the BH register prior to `div bx`. Also where have the brackets gone in your comment?

```
mov ax, word ptr c+2
mov dx, word ptr c
add ax, word ptr c
```

Here you're doing it all wrong. The result of the **new word division** will be in AX. So add the low word of *c* to AX and add with carry the high word of *c* to an empty DX register.

```
mov word ptr x+2, dx
mov word ptr x, ax
```

Seems OK.